# "Node.insertBefore is not an object" error

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new in JavaScript. And I've follow [this tutorial](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/simplest-javascript-slideshow) to create my first project a very simple image slideshow. This is my complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Dummy Slideshow</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.fadein { position:relative; height:332px; width:500px;}
.fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; transition:opacity 1s; opacity:1; }
.fadein img.is-hidden { opacity:0; }
</style>
<div class="fadein">
  <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg">
  <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2597/4121218611_040cd7b3f2.jpg">
  <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4121218751_ac8bf49d5d.jpg">
</div>
<script>
  var root = document.querySelector('.fadein');
  var els = root.querySelectorAll(':not(:first-child)');
  for (i=0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].classList.add('is-hidden');
  }
  root.addEventListener('transitionend', function(){
    root.insertBefore(root.querySelector(':first-child.is-hidden'), null);
  });
  setInterval(function(){
    root.querySelector(':first-child').classList.add('is-hidden');
    root.querySelector(':nth-child(2)').classList.remove('is-hidden');
  }, 3000)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works pretty well at first, until when I try to activate firebug, it's showing error:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.insertBefore is not an object.
```

The error refferences to this part:

```
root.addEventListener('transitionend', function(){
   root.insertBefore(root.querySelector(':first-child.is-hidden'), null);
});
```

I've try to replace `:first-child.is-hidden` with `.is-hidden:nth-of-type(1)` too but the error it still appears. The error somehow disappears when I remove `:first-child`, but it will make the slideshow fail to show all picture.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: don't chain dom calls like that. if `querySelector` doesn't find anything, it'll return `null`, which you then blindly pass to `insertBefore`, which is expecting a DOMNode, not a `null`.

Comment: I think you're using the css first-child psedoclass in a very strange way. node.insertBefore(newnode,existingnode) existingnode is optional, but you set it as null.

Comment: @MarcB thanks, after I saw rishabh answer, I realize the problem you both said. But, I thinks it's weird for me because in my experience (not in javascript) this kind of error should be a runtime error doesn't it? the error which only happen when `querySelector` doesn't find anything

Comment: @Observer but in this site, it said not an optional: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

transitionend event is triggered two times. One after add('is-hidden'); and other after remove('is-hidden'). Second time ':first-child.is-hidden' element is null

```js
var root = document.querySelector('.fadein');
var els = root.querySelectorAll(':not(:first-child)');
for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  els[i].classList.add('is-hidden');
}

root.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
  if(root.querySelector(':first-child.is-hidden'))
  root.insertBefore(root.querySelector(':first-child.is-hidden'), null);
});
setInterval(function() {
  root.querySelector(':first-child').classList.add('is-hidden');
 root.querySelector(':nth-child(2)').classList.remove('is-hidden');
}, 3000)
```

```css
 .fadein {
   position: relative;
   height: 332px;
   width: 500px;
 }
 .fadein img {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   transition: opacity 1s;
   opacity: 1;
 }
 .fadein img.is-hidden {
   opacity: 0;
 }
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="fadein">
    <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg">
    <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2597/4121218611_040cd7b3f2.jpg">
    <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4121218751_ac8bf49d5d.jpg">
  </div>

</body>
```